# Render Google Login Button with PHP Code

Tags: php, google-oauth, google-signin

With this code I can render a Google+ Login Button on my website:

```
<span id="signinButton">
  <span
    class="g-signin"
    data-callback="signinCallback"
    data-clientid="CLIENT_ID"
    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
    data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
    data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">
  </span>
</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() 
    {
       var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
       po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
       var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
     })();
</script>
```

Is there an equivalent php code with which I can render a Google+ Login Button on my website? I do not want to use any JavaScript for that because the user can disable it and then the button is not displayed.